# Signal Processing Question--old school

Tags: audio, signal, sampling

I have a signal generator that creates a mostly 8kHz sine wave signal, with a couple quirks.  It repeats in a 96ms pattern.  Output is 220mV into a 1-20 ohm wire.  It is used to provide wire guidance to a wire-guided robot mower.  The mower is old and the signal generators used to control it are obsolete and nearly impossible to find.  The signal is more than just a 8kHz signal and smarter heads than mine have tried to reverse engineer the signal generator with no luck.  I was wondering if I could use audio equipment, record the signal from a working generator, then repeat play it in a CD/SD player over the wire to replace the signal generator?  Does this make any sense?  I am mostly concerned about voltage levels in experimentation.  Don't want to get too complicated or fry any equipment.  I have very little audio equipment, so would have to buy anything I used and budget is important.  TIA.  Mark.

Comment: Are you certain it's a fixed, repeating pattern, and not one that carries some information?

Answer (score 0):

I think it‘s a good idea to use audio equipment in your case for analyzing and driving purpose, although oscilloscope and signal generator are the first choice in most cases, because they are more versatile.

One thing you have to find out is the signal driving method. Is the signal a current source (what I would expect in this application) or is it a voltage source (220mV fixed amplitude, no matter what the cable resistance is)? Try to alter the resistance and see what happens.